# Pyspark: Column is not iterable(expr,format_string)

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working a spark dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

I d like to substract(if its utc-)/add(if its utc+) "utc_time" amount of hours to a "local2" datetime. I d like to do it using expr function. What I want to use is, if "utc" is +, add the "utc_time" to the "local2" date time. Below you can see the code I have:

```
df = df.withColumn('updated_local', when((substring('utc', 4, 1))=='+',(df.local2 + expr(format_string("INTERVAL %s HOURS", "utc_time"))) ).otherwise('whatever'))
```

But I get an 'Column is not iterable' error when using this.

If I don't use format string and construct it like this, it works:

```
    df = df.withColumn('updated_local', when((substring('utc', 4, 1))=='+',(df.local2 + expr("INTERVAL 10 HOURS")) ).otherwise('whatever'))
```

I appreciate methods other than expr function, if you guys have any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below, it shoud work :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
 df.withColumn('updated_local', when((substring(col('utc'), 4, 1))=='+', concat(col('local2'), lit("INTERVAL "), col('utc_time'), lit(" HOURS utc_time"))).otherwise('whatever'))
```

best regards